# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, firebase

Intento cargar el modulo de nodemailer, usando firebase

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

Comment: en que parte del codigo estas cargando ese modulo ? podrias poner la clase completa?

Comment: Comentaste que te faltaba aregar en el directorio raiz de public el archivo package.json

{
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.2"
  }
} ? ya encontraste la solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionando, tenia mal creados los directorios del proyecto ademas el index.js mal ubicado, seguí esto al pie de la letra y me funciona perfecto los módulos cargados con requiere.
https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e